# Cut faces where they intersect with the mesh

Tags: modifiers, faces, shortcut, knife-tool

I exported an object from a game and I am working to clean it up so I can 3d print it. I am almost finished, however I have a small issue with the gun barrel, where I created some new faces to close a gap but ended up with them passing through the barrel tube.

I believe a boolean is necessary but I am very inexperienced with Blender as a whole, leaving me stumped on how to proceed. What can I do to cut these selected faces out of the inner barrel?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In Edit Mode (Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle), Loop select the front inner ring of edges of the barrel by placing your cursor over one of the edges that goes around the circle and hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. Separate this from your mesh by hitting <kbd>P</kbd> >> <kbd>S</kbd>.
3. Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to Toggle back into object mode.
4. <kbd>RMB</kbd> over the inner ring to select it.
5. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the mesh that you need to cut.
6. Now go into front view <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>.
7. Make sure that your toolshelf is open at the left - <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle.
8. Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle back into edit mode.
9. Select all (Verts / Faces).
10. On the toolshelf use "Knife Project" - There is a checkbox on the bottom left hand side of the toolshelf that says "Cut Through", make sure you check it.
11. Now just delete the edges and faces that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to select the faces that must cut the others and duplicate them. Make sure that, after duplicating, only those faces are selected. Than hit P, and click 'selection'. Now, go out of edit mode. You now have an extra object, which is the object you want to use to cut the others. Make sure that it is not a set of faces, but make it solid by using the Solidify modifier or by filling in any gaps in edit mode. Now, select the object you want to cut, add a boolean modifier, set it to difference and select the object you got from the duplication. this might do the trick, but sometimes different solutions, like using the knife tool are necessary.